# jQuery - Text toggles only once

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple script that should change from `+` to `-`
when the `Content` is open, and backwards.
But now, when it changes to `-`, it stays as `-` no matter what.
Even if you collapse the content, it still stays as `-`.

I've tried to reverse the functions, but it just did the same with the `+`.

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#expanderHead").click(function(){
        $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
    if ($("#expanderSign").text() != "+"){
        $("#expanderSign").html("-")
    } else {
        $("#expanderSign").html("+")
    }
    });
});
```

---

### HTML

```
<span id="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;">
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.
    <span id="expanderSign">+
    </span></span>
    <div id="expanderContent" style="display:none; color: green;">
    <sup><p>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum,<br>
     Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum.</p>
     </sup>
  </div>
```

Comment: your if block has the content of else block and your else block have the condition of if block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your logic is wrong, you're saying if the sign is not currently `+` (it is `-`), then set it to `-`. The sign will always be `-`.

Change your condition to:

```
if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "+"){
```

Or how about using a function with your [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) method:

```
$("#expanderSign").text(function(i,v){
    return v == '-' ? '+' : '-';
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjsMe/)

Answer (score 4):

Your condition check logic is the wrong way around, try this:

```
if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "+"){
    $("#expanderSign").html("-")
}
else {
    $("#expanderSign").html("+")
}
```

Comment: Now it works the opposite. It displays plus on expand and minus on collapse.

Answer (score 4):

If it's **not** plus, i.e. minus, you want to change it **to** a plus.

```
if($("#expanderSign").html() != "+") { // is anything but a '+'
    $("#expanderSign").html("+");
}
else { // is a '+'
    $("#expanderSign").html("-");
}
```

You do not see any change in your code because you are changing minus signs to a minus, and plus signs to a plus.

Answer (score 3):

You are saying that if it is not `!=` equal to plus *i.e. it is minus* that you should make it minus:

```
if ($("#expanderSign").text() != "+"){
    $("#expanderSign").html("-");
```

So just change `!=` to `==`:

```
if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "+"){
    $("#expanderSign").html("-");
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic is backwards on which sign to display. See fiddle below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#expanderHead").click(function () {
        $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
        // Backwards logic
        if ($("#expanderSign").text() != "-") {
            $("#expanderSign").html("-");
        } else {
            $("#expanderSign").html("+");
        }
    });
});
```

[1](http://jsfiddle.net/5R9Ys/)

Answer (score 1):

"If it does not = + set it to minus"

Basically, if it = '-' set it to '-' is what you have ti set to now. Try changing that != to ==.

Answer (score 0):

**in HTML :**

```
<span id="expanderSign">+</span>
no carriage return-------^
```

**in JS :**

```
$("#expanderSign").html($("#expanderSign").html() != "+" ? "+" : "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working myself actually.
It's a bit hacky, but works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                                var expanded = false;
                                var collapsed = true;
                                $("#expanderHead").click(function(){
                                    if (expanded == true) {
                                        expanded = false;
                                        collapsed = true;
                                    } else {
                                        expanded = true;
                                        collapsed = false;
                                    }

                                if (expanded == true) {
                                    $("#expanderSign").html("-");
                                    $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();}

                                if (collapsed == true) {
                                    $("#expanderSign").html("+");
                                    $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();}
                                });
                            });
```

Comment: There are way better solutions that have been provided to you here. I applaud your effort in solving the issue yourself but I'd also like to encourage you try out some of the solutions below and accept one of them as an answer rather then posting your own and robbing them of the points they deserve. At the very least click that little up arrow next to their answers.